# reviews format for external program or system

Tags: bug-report, review

I have some tasks to do for reviews, 
but the program that I will reviewed was not mine.. 

It comes from external and nothing documentations of it.. 

I already run test on it and it delivered some bugs. 


How can I make review for this program?

Can I have some template for it?

Best regards,

Ahmad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First google Exploratory Testing.
Some ideas for testing might be-

- yours, and your customer's expectations and needs (what is the program used for)
- similar programs (compare to other knowns)
- relevant standards, or de-facto and industry standards (from national or international standard bodies e.g. ISO/IEEE/FDA etc. other sources might be known practices)

some more good ideas can be found in [37 Sources for Test Ideas](http://thetesteye.com/posters/TheTestEye_SourcesForTestIdeas.pdf)